# Implement One-to-One Relationship in SQL without sharing PKs?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to define a one-to-one relationship between two tables in a database, let's say Person and Address.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  pid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  occupation VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Address (
  street VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  city VARCHAR(10),
  state VARCHAR(2),
  zip VARCHAR(5));
```

I want to link these two, so that each Person has exactly one Address, and each Address has exactly one Person living there (it is a simplified example).

Most solutions I have found recommend having the two tables share a primary key, or changing the PK of Address to a FK referencing the PK of Person. I don't want to do this though, because I still want both street and pid to be unique all on their own.

How would I go about approaching this?

Comment: Why one-to-one? One person can have several addresses...

Comment: Note that several peoples can live on the same street. You'll not be able to add another record if street will be a PK.

Comment: @MaciejLos It is a simplified example, but let's say for instance that this is a strict apartment complex that only allows each person to rent a single apartment in the complex.

Comment: so... do not divide data to person and address tables ;) Have you ever heard about 1., 2. and 3. level of optimization form database?

Comment: @MaciejLos Would I not then be wasting space in the Person table for each person in the table who does not have a corresponding address? I want to avoid combining the tables because I may have a number of Person tuples without addresses, or a number of Address tuples without residents. They are standalone entities, as far as I can tell.

Comment: There's nothing like "wasting space". I do not know your requirements.. At this time, i think, you need to re-think your database model.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have a unique key on the Person, as well as a primary key, and the primary key of address would reference that.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to @DavidAldridge's suggestion, I'd structure the tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
  (ID_ADDRESS  NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_ADDRESS
       PRIMARY KEY,
   ADDR1            VARCHAR2(100),
   ADDR2            VARCHAR2(100),
   CITY             VARCHAR2(100),
   STATE_ABBR       CHAR(2),
   POSTAL_CODE      VARCHAR2(9));

CREATE TABLE PERSON
  (ID_PERSON        NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON
       PRIMARY KEY,
   ID_ADDRESS       NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_1
       REFERENCES ADDRESS (ID_ADDRESS)
     CONSTRAINT UQ_PERSON_1
       UNIQUE,
   FIRST_NAME       VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'JENNIE',
   LAST_NAME        VARCHAR2(50),
   AGE              NUMBER,
   WEIGHT           NUMBER,
   PHONE            VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT '867-5309');
```

(The assumption here is that ID_ADDRESS and ID_PERSON will be filled with unique values in some manner - if it was me I'd be doing this in a BEFORE INSERT trigger on each of these tables...).

By putting a UNIQUE constraint on PERSON.ID_ADDRESS you're saying that only one person can live at a given address.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.